# error al llenar la fila [4][] de una matriz c++

Tags: c++, codeblocks

tengo una matriz que solo puede admitir hasta 5 registros máximo (serian filas),
pero tengo un problema con el método que me las incluye lo que pasa es que luego del registro 3 cuando ingreso el cuarto se me pega la consola, nose cual sea el problema, agradezco sus ayudas.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void guardarCliente(string[][3] ,string,string,double, char,int);


void guardarCliente(string registroClientes[][3] ,string dni,string nombreCompleto,double salarioMensual, char ordenPatronal,int contador){

    if(contador>5){

        system("cls");
        cout<<"-----------------------------------------"<<endl;
        cout<<"Maximo de Clientes Alcanzados :"<<contador<<endl;
        cout<<"-----------------------------------------"<<endl;
    }else{

        try{

            registroClientes[contador][0] = dni;
            registroClientes[contador][1] = nombreCompleto;
            registroClientes[contador][2] = salarioMensual;
            registroClientes[contador][3] = ordenPatronal;
     
            

        }catch(int error){

             cout<<"Error al Guardar Usuario :"<<error<<endl;
        }

    }

    system("cls");
    cout<<"-------------------------------------"<<endl;
    cout<<"Registro Realizado Safistactoriamente"<<endl;
    cout<<"-------------------------------------"<<endl;
    cout<<"Clientes Registrados:     "<<contador<<endl;
    cout<<"-------------------------------------"<<endl;
    system("pause");



}

int main()
{

    double salarioMensual;
    string nombreCompleto;
    string dni;
    char ordenPatronal;
    string registroClientes[5][3];

    int contadorGuardado = 0;

                cout<<"-------------------------------------------------------------"<<endl;
                cout<<"Ingrese su Numero de Identificacion (No se permiten guiones) "<<endl;
                cout<<"-------------------------------------------------------------"<<endl;
                cin>>dni;



        cout<<"----------------------------------------------------------"<<endl;
            cout<<"             Ingrese su Nombre Completo                   "<<endl;
            cout<<"----------------------------------------------------------"<<endl;
            cin.ignore();
            getline(cin,nombreCompleto);


            cout<<"----------------------------------------------------------"<<endl;
            cout<<"             Ingrese su Ingreso Mensual                   "<<endl;
            cout<<"----------------------------------------------------------"<<endl;
            cout<<"No ingrese comas ni puntos, el programa lo hara por usted."<<endl;
            cin>>salarioMensual;


                cout<<"----------------------------------------------------------"<<endl;
                cout<<"            Cuenta con Orden Patronal                     "<<endl;
                cout<<"----------------------------------------------------------"<<endl;
                cout<<"  S / N                                                   "<<endl;
                cout<<"----------------------------------------------------------"<<endl;
                cin>>ordenPatronal;

contadorGuardado++;
    

            guardarCliente(registroClientes, dni, nombreCompleto,salarioMensual, ordenPatronal,contadorGuardado);


}
```

aquí les dejo el código para que lo prueben, el método que **guardarCliente** es el que tiene el problema, cuando sobrepaso el 3 registro se traba no entiendo porque debería ser capaz de permitir 5 ingresos de filas del a matriz, solo permite 3.

**lo que pasa es que no e podido emplear el uso de for, porque cuando hago un for yo ocupo que la matriz se llene con un cliente diferente en cada fila, pero si hago un for se me llena toda la matriz con un solo cliente.**

Comment: No hay ninguna excepción que capturar así que el **try catch** es innecesario.

Comment: aun si borro los while y todo eso, el problema sigue, cuando lleno la matriz y empieza a llenarse la fila 3 , cuando paso a la fila 4 el programa se cae

Comment: Será más fácil si haces un [example] donde dices qué sucede y qué debería suceder. Puedes usar alguna página como [esta](https://tio.run/#cpp-gcc) para obtener los errores de compilación y mostrar el comportamiento que estás obteniendo.

Comment: la matriz es 5x3 , solo quiero llenar todos los espacios jejeje

Answer (score 0):

Lamentablemente me faltan 9 puntos para poder comentar, soy nuevo. Solamente puedo comentar por acá. Traté de suponer algunas cosas porque tu código no está completo. Te dejo el código que escribí para que lo revises. Trata de poner el código completo la próxima vez para que podamos probarlo y ser más puntual cuando buscamos el error.

Recordá que no se pueden guardar datos de distintos tipos en una matríz.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
string registroClientes[5][4];

void mostrarMatriz(int cont, string matr[5][3]){
    for (int i=0 ; i<4 ; i++){
        cout << matr[cont][i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}

void guardarCliente(string registroClientes[][3] ,string dni,string nombreCompleto,string salarioMensual, char ordenPatronal,int contador){
    if(contador>5){
        system("cls");
        cout<<"-----------------------------------------"<<endl;
        cout<<"Maximo de Clientes Alcanzados :"<<contador<<endl;
        cout<<"-----------------------------------------"<<endl;
    }else{
        try{
            registroClientes[contador][0] = dni;
            registroClientes[contador][1] = nombreCompleto;
            registroClientes[contador][2] = salarioMensual;
            registroClientes[contador][3] = ordenPatronal;
            mostrarMatriz(contador, registroClientes);
            system("pause");
            }catch(int error){
                cout<<"Error al Guardar Usuario :"<<error<<endl;
            }

    }

    system("cls");
    cout<<"-------------------------------------"<<endl;
    cout<<"Registro Realizado Safistactoriamente"<<endl;
    cout<<"-------------------------------------"<<endl;
    cout<<"Clientes Registrados:     "<<contador<<endl;
    cout<<"-------------------------------------"<<endl;
    system("pause");
}

bool esEntero(string a) {
    if ( a.length() < 9 ) return false;
    return true; 
}

string separarDigitos(string a){
    cout << "no se que hace la función separarDigitos(), perdón " << endl ;
    return a;
}

string nombreCompleto, dni;
char ordenPatronal;
int salarioMensual;
int contadorGuardado = 0;

int main() {
    string registroClientes[5][3];
        do
        {
            cout<<"-------------------------------------------------------------"<<endl;
            cout<<"Ingrese su Numero de Identificacion (No se permiten guiones) "<<endl;
            cout<<"-------------------------------------------------------------"<<endl;
            cin>>dni;
            system("cls");
            while(!esEntero(dni)){

                cout<<"No se permiten guiones :"<<endl;
                cin>>dni;
            }
        }while(!esEntero(dni));
        system("cls");
        cout<<"----------------------------------------------------------"<<endl;
        cout<<"             Ingrese su Nombre Completo                   "<<endl;
        cout<<"----------------------------------------------------------"<<endl;
        cin.ignore();
        getline(cin,nombreCompleto);

        system("cls");
        cout<<"----------------------------------------------------------"<<endl;
        cout<<"             Ingrese su Ingreso Mensual                   "<<endl;
        cout<<"----------------------------------------------------------"<<endl;
        cout<<"No ingrese comas ni puntos, el programa lo hara por usted."<<endl;
        cin>>salarioMensual;

            while(salarioMensual<0){
                system("cls");
                cout<<"No se permiten valores negativos :"<<endl;
                cin>>salarioMensual;
            }
        do  {
            system("cls");
            cout<<"----------------------------------------------------------"<<endl;
            cout<<"            Cuenta con Orden Patronal                     "<<endl;
            cout<<"----------------------------------------------------------"<<endl;
            cout<<"  S / N                                                   "<<endl;
            cout<<"----------------------------------------------------------"<<endl;
            cin>>ordenPatronal;

            while(ordenPatronal != 'S' && ordenPatronal != 'N'){

                system("cls");
                cout<<"Solo Digitos S / N"<<endl;
                cin>>ordenPatronal;
            }

        }while(ordenPatronal != 'S' && ordenPatronal != 'N');

        contadorGuardado++;

        cout<<contadorGuardado;
        system("pause");

        guardarCliente(registroClientes, dni, nombreCompleto,separarDigitos(to_string(salarioMensual)), ordenPatronal,contadorGuardado);

}
```

Comment: a ok perdón dejame editar la pregunta y meto todo el codigo

Comment: Ya que estás haciendo la no-respuesta, al menos indícale al OP qué revisar en el código. Pues, digo, como para que todos los que lean sepan por qué ese código es relevante o qué cambios tiene, esas cosas...

Comment: OP que es perdon

Comment: @Esther vos sos OP. El autor de la pregunta.